# Disable keyboard shortcuts

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

Using C#, I made a form maximized without showing the toolbar, but I need to disable all keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, etc) including <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>. Can I do this?

Comment: No, you can't.  It is the user's system, and at the end of the day *they* have control over *their* system, not your program.  There is too much potential for malicious abuse or other security vulnerabilities if you could do all of that.  Even if you could do it, you shouldn't.  There are better ways of accomplishing whatever it is you *really* need to do.

Comment: I have a quiz application,and I don't want user to do anything that is not related with application.How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Don't give the user's sufficient privileges to do whatever you don't want them to do.

Comment: One way to do it is to enable direct x input in exclusive mode. It's a bit more advanced than winforms though.

Comment: What if user has 2 computers and use the second to search for answers?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use OnPreviewKeyDown (in WPF) event. Where you can identify what user entered and control based on key combinations.

Comment: I am not using WPF...I am using Winform

Comment: Textbox in Winform have a previewkeydown event. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown.aspx. I hope it helps.